# Disable Virtualbox guest additions for Testkitchen

Tags: test-kitchen

For tests in Testkitchen I use Vagrant base box with an older version of VirtualBox guest additions. So every time I run tests it updates guest additions first

```
==> default: Machine booted and ready!                                                                                                     
[default] GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.1.28) and guest (5.0.8) do not match.
```

I do not need this update because mounting filesystem actually works with no problem. I would like to disable it.

I quickly checked the docs for `kitchen-vagrant` and disabled VBox additions update by creating `VagranfileKitchen.rb` with:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false
end
```

and by adding to `.kitchen.yml`:

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  vagrantfiles:
    - VagrantfileKitchen.rb
```

I wonder if there is a cleaner way without additional files? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I think the best solution is to update your base box regularly.  But if you don't want to do that, then you can add this to your `~/vagrant.d/Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false
end
```

This way you don't need to add anything to `.kitchen.yml`, which makes this method marginally simpler than your given solution, with the caveat that it will affect all of your Vagrant boxes, and not just your TestKitchen boxes.

Comment: I will have to do it on every machine, or everyone who clones the repo. I still think that my solution is better :|

Comment: @Derp you do not, actually.  When you create a vagrant image, you can optionally bundle a Vagrantfile with it that gets executed whenever an instance of the image is created.  So you can just put the common code into the bundled Vagrantfile.